# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'long'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a Naive Bayes Classifier using sklearn on the:
[Breast Cancer Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/).
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

col = ['ID','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','class']
data =pd.read_csv("data.csv",names = col,header =None)
data = data.drop('ID',axis =1)
msk = np.random.rand(len(data)) < 0.66
train =  data[msk]
test = data[~msk]
y = train['class']
X = train.drop('class',axis = 1)
labels = test['class']
test = test.drop('class',axis = 1)
clf = GaussianNB()
'''
y1 = np.array(y, dtype=pd.Series)
X1 = np.array(X,dtype = pd.Series)
'''
clf.fit(X, y)
```

The data set is divided into 66% training set and 33% test set ratio. I use a Gaussian NB Classifier using sklearn.
When I run it,I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-3c90e612af8d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/Breast Cancer/main1a.py', wdir='C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/Breast Cancer')

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/Breast Cancer/main1a.py", line 37, in <module>
    clf.fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 163, in fit
    self.theta_[i, :] = np.mean(Xi, axis=0)

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2727, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 69, in _mean
    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'long'
```

With the same training set and test set, I was able to run SVM(sklearn) successfully but not so with GaussianNB.

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: `X1 = np.array(X,dtype = pd.Series)` seems wrong. `np.Series` is not a valid dtype and you will end up with dtype `object`

Comment: @cel
Okay... The same error comes with X too!

Comment: you should make sure that your input had a numeric dtype, like ``np.float64``. sklearn will be more robust towards that in the future, but you should still try to make sure.